# Original Google Web-Search with Autocomplete on own Homepage

Tags: html, ajax

I want to use the normal web-search with autocomplete from Google on a own page. Not custom-search! Just the normal one like www.google.com.
I can't find a example or how-to for that. Only for custom-search-engine (cse) with Google. But that's not what I want.

Can anyone provide a link or a HTML construct on how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If there is no dedicated API to do what you want to do, you're out of luck. Google's policies don't allow you to scrape results pages, for example. From the [Terms of Service](https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/):

> (...) For example, don’t interfere with our Services or try to access them using a method other than the interface and the instructions that we provide. (...)

It looks like you should either use CSE or a similar API to query Google for search results, or use a different search engine, for example Yahoo!'s [BOSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/boss/#pricing) service.